# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UInt32'

Tags: ios, swift, integer, arc4random, uint32

I am trying to generate a random number in Swift:

```
var amountOfQuestions = 2
var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(amountOfQuestions - 1)) + 1
```

but this results in the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UInt32'

What is the problem? Any ideas on what I can do to fix this error?

Comment: Did you try casting (amountOfQuestions - 1) to UInt32?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your `amountOfQuestions` variable an `UInt32` rather than an `Int` inferred by the compiler.

```
var amountOfQuestions: UInt32 = 2

// ...

var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(amountOfQuestions - 1)) + 1
```

`arc4random_uniform` requires a `UInt32`.

From the [Darwin docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html):

```
arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t upper_bound);
```

Comment: Furthermore, it's worth noting that if `amountOfQuestions` is computed, for instance from the size of an array, the appropriate answer might just be to cast it to UInt32 using the constructor, ie., UInt32(questions.count).

Answer (score 7):

Declare amountOfQuestions as a UInt32:

```
var amountOfQuestions: UInt32 = 2
```

PS: If you want to be grammatically correct it's *number* of questions.

Answer (score 5):

First thing:
The method "arc4random_uniform" expects an argument of type UInt32, so when you put that subtraction there, it converted the '1' you wrote to UInt32.

Second thing: In swift you can't subtract a UInt32 (the '1' in your formula) from an Int (in this case 'amountOfQuestions').

To solve it all, you'll have to consider changing the declaration of 'amountOfQuestions' to:

```
var amountOfQuestions = UInt32(2)
```

That should do the trick :)

Comment: Your second part, while partially true (it's true that you can't subtract a UInt32 from an Int), is irrelevant.  In this case the 1 will automatically be the appropriate type, in this case an Int to match amountOfQuestions for the subtraction to work.  The problem is that that Int can't be passed to arc4random_uniform, which expects a UInt32 argument.  Note that it's perfectly valid to use `UInt32(2) - 1` and the result is also a UInt32 (which is why your actual fix works)

Comment: The second part was used to complete the thought. In the code presented by the question, amountOfQuestions wasn't an UInt32. There was only one solution in my answer, I just broke in two for him to understand it better. What you said about being perfect valid to UInt32 is known and totally irrelevant too....